# User control's contents not created or even parsed

Tags: .net, asp.net, user-controls

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 application with some simple user controls. The user controls work fine on the design surface (VS.NET 2010), but when they're loaded during application execution, nothing shows up.

Furthermore, the various child controls of the user controls are null when referenced inside the code behind for the user control.

The code behind for the user control executes as expected, but any reference to child controls are null.

It's like ASP.NET is never parsing the .ascx to create the instances of the child controls.

Ideas?

Comment: How are you adding the usercontrols to the page? Are you using LoadControl("...")?

Comment: They're added via the ASPX markup. I have the namespace declaration in the web.config, and I then reference that namespace and the control name is the ASPX file. Standard stuff.

I even get intellisense when I do it, so I know it's working.

Comment: You probably do need to post some code then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was just me being extremely stupid.

My web.config was missing the propery control namespace references.